# Extracting content from Jar file

Tags: java

I'm looking for a way to extract data from a jar file.
What i need is information about a certain class file including:
- Constructor name
- Public methods (getters, setters and actions.)
- Perhaps if included the javadoc

For example, in Eclipse, when you type your variable and you press '.' behind it, it gives a complete list of methods, so i'm guessing there should be a way to find this data out. (I'd only need the names of the methods, not the actual code.)

Some actual code, pseudocode, instructions or anything else is appreciated.

Comment: I've used [Apache Commons BCEL API](http://commons.apache.org/bcel/manual.html) to extract information about Java classes in the past, it might be useful for you.  Jar's are just "special" Zip files.  You can use [JarFile](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/jar/JarFile.html) to open and extract the data from them.  Remember, if the Jar/classes aren't loaded within the context of your applications class loader, you won't be able to use reflection to inspect them

Comment: Does it need to be "from a jar"?  You can use reflection to get list of constructors and methods from a class though class is loaded through standard classloading.  This won't have javadocs, but if you're looking for class member metadata at runtime, consider annotations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Extract the jar as a simple zip with ZipFile, as shown in this page:
http://www.java-examples.com/extract-zip-file-subdirectories-using-command-line-argument-example

Then, for each .class file found, use the ClassParser: http://commons.apache.org/bcel/apidocs/org/apache/bcel/classfile/ClassParser.html

**A quicker way:**

Also with ClassParser's constructor [ClassParser(String zipFile, String fileName)](http://commons.apache.org/bcel/apidocs/org/apache/bcel/classfile/ClassParser.html#ClassParser%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) you can get every information you want about the `fileName` class in your `zipFile`

Comment: Thanks mate! That will do it. Could you give some more information what I should use to extract the jar as a zip file?

Comment: Check this link: http://www.java-examples.com/extract-zip-file-subdirectories-using-command-line-argument-example

Comment: Thanks guys, got i working! Cheers. If anyone is looking for the code, ask me

Answer (score -1):

You can view the types in the jar files using JD-GUI ( a decompiler ).
or
You can extract the jar file just like you would do with a zip file. Then you can use javap to view members of the class.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, but I was looking for a way to do this programmatically.